# Can't start/execute an array of threads from a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I have an array of threads which needs to return some value after completion of work.
Everything works fine if I create separate thread variable(s) but not through loop.

```
public temp ()
        {
            int count = 10; // comes from function

            int[] ret = new int[count] // return value array
            Cls[] cls = new Cls[count]; // Class instance array
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[count]; // threads array

            // Main LOOP
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                cls[i] = new Cls('\0', 1); // create new class instances
                threads[i] = new Thread(state => 
                {
                    ret[i] = cls.SomeMethod('some', 'thing'); // SomeMethod returns int which I need to store 
                });
            }

            // *** 1st TRY ***
            //-----------------------
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Start() // (error)
            }

            // *** 2nd TRY ***
            //------------------------
            threads[0].Start();
            threads[1].Start(); 
            //.....
        }
```

**1st TRY :**
For some reason when I reach threads[i].Start() inside (2nd) loop it gives array 'Out of bound' error because i (of the main loop) becomes 3 .... why & how ?

**2nd TRY :** Error: System.__ComObject cannot be cast into interface...(<- this error is 
not part of my question.) My question is :

If I assign/start the threads separately (not in loop) like

**thread1 = {...};**

**thread2 = {...}**... and then start each thread

**thread1.Start();**

**thread2.Start();**.... everything goes well but why not from loops ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *[closing over the loop counter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)*.

Basically, change it to this:

```
// Main LOOP
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // this is fine referring to i, because it's not in a lambda:
    cls[i] = new Cls('\0', 1);
    int j = i; // create a new variable for the lambda
    threads[i] = new Thread(state => 
    {
        // here you must refer to j, not i, because you're in a lambda
        ret[j] = cls.SomeMethod('some', 'thing');
    });
}
```

What is happening is that the code inside your lamda expression is referring to `i` the *variable*, not the current *value* of `i` when you create the thread. They are all referring to the same variable in memory.

So by the time you start your threads, `i` is equal to `count`, and you get index out of range when your thread code tries to access `ret[i]`.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard! This made my day. Really appreciate :)